# How to draw a circle on mapView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview

I am developing an application in which I have to show a mapView.
What I exactly want to do is when user click on radius button, there should be circle drawn of that radius with the center point as the current location.
Please tell me how can I draw a filled circle on my map that indicate the radius from the current location.

Any help will be highly appreciated
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: may I know what is mean by radius button here?

Comment: sure radius button corresponds to the values like 2,3,4 etc...

Comment: how did u solve this problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a new instance of MKCircle with appropriate center and radius, and then add it to the map view's overlays. MKCircle in a subclass of MKOverlay, so you can handle it like any other overlay. Example:

```
MKCircle *myCircle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:myCenterPoint radius:myRadius];
[myMapView addOverlay:myCircle];
```

I'll leave it to you to substitute "current location" and user-selected radius for myCenterPoint and myRadius in the code above.

Comment: thanks it works for me but there is a single problem I have customize my current user location annotation and given my user location coordinates in myCenterPoint but my user location is not coming at center of my circle

Answer (score 3):

If you want to draw anything on a map your best friend is MKOverlay.. Search in Google for MKOverlay tutorials.

[MKCircle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKCircle_class/Reference/Reference.html) is the Class which you want to know about. Just read the docs to get to know some idea

Just see circleWithCenterCoordinate:radius